# Dredge with the global model failing to converge

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am trying to run gamm models with multiple variable combinations in dredge (MuMIn) framework, with a cutoff based TRUE/FALSE correlation matrix as subset.

Problem is, my full model is quite complex with random effects, `>20` predictor variables including 3 fixed effects, and therefore won't converge. My predictors are highly correlated, as mentioned I included a TRUE/FALSE correlation matrix as subset. Due a low correlation cutoff I expect very few combinations and not really interested in the full model.

However, my construction of gamm (or uGamm) full model, which includes 20+ predictors (smoothed terms and fixed effects, random effects) does not converge. This essentially means that dredge won't run since the full model doesn't converge, even though I am not interested in the full model per se, rather in the single models and a few combinations.

It also appears that I cant use `fm1 <- gamm(y ~ (.), data = Cement)` option, as this gives the following error:

> Error in s(.) : s(.) not yet supported

Is there a way to bypass the full model which will not converge and have my variable combinations regardless? and/Or is there a way to avoid the above error with `(.)`?

Any suggestions? my data is too large to include here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trick `dredge` by replacing the formula in a simpler model, and then use that model as a "global model". Assign the full model formula to `<gam.model> $ gam $ formula`. For example:

```
# fit some simple model
fm <- uGamm(y ~ s(x1), ...) # add other arguments as in the proper full model
fm$gam$formula <- y ~ x0 + s(x1) + s(x2) + ... + s(xn)
dredge(fm)
```

Comment: how would you trick dredge r rather code this..assuming the full model is "fmgs1 <- gamm4(y ~ x0+ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)...s(xn), family = poisson,
+     data = dat, random = ~(1 | fac))"

Comment: I actually used 'fmgs1 <- uGamm(y ~ x0, ...)' and this model wont converge, hence my original question on whether there is a way around this

Comment: You have to find some formulation that converges. Otherwise, if none of your subset models converge, the whole procedure doesn't make sense.

Comment: I first fit the simple model as you suggested 'fm <- uGamm(y ~ x0 + s(x1), family = poisson,  data = dat, random = ~(1 | fac), ...)' , second I fit the full model with 'fm$gam$formula' as the prefix, obviously it failed to converge. dredge(fm) returned outputs for only the simple model..it wasnt tricked afterall

Comment: yes indeed the simple model did converge...I meant the full model didnt converge..and after following your instructions as I have described above, dredge returns outputs for the simple model :(

Comment: seems to be running..i didnt follow your instructions correctly. the second bit..fm$gam$formula..shouldnt include 'other model arguments'. Do you reckon subsets arguments in dredge will work fine in this trick?

Comment: The global model terms in `"gamm"` are taken from the `gam$formula` element, so once you have replaced it, `dredge` should work as if it was a valid model.

Comment: dredge model appears to be running fine but it has been now running for the last 10 hrs and still going! yet I have only 25 variables and I have set my m.max= 2, including  a subset option. I suspect there is a problem

Comment: You can check whether the generated model calls are correct by setting arguments `evaluate=FALSE` or `trace=TRUE`.

Comment: Works fine now. I want to save the object returned by dredge and be able to read it in later,,is there such a functionality? couldn't find anythng in the documentation..