# (MuMIn) Dredge when global mixed-effects model is rank deficient

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to run variable selection on Poisson mixed-effect models using `glmer()` and `dredge()`. Since several variables are collinear I use the subsetting function of `dredge` to avoid correlated variables. However, to use `dredge()` effectively one needs to have a full model including all terms - which can lead to full model to be rank-deficient.

[edited Feb 15 2016] To give a reproducible example, let's generate a random data set:

```
dfdat<-data.frame(replicate(6, round(rnorm(6),2)))
dfdat$group<-factor(sample(1:2,nrow(dfdat),replace=T))
dfdat$Y<-rpois(nrow(dfdat),10)+rpois(nrow(dfdat),as.numeric(dfdat$group))
dfdat
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6 group  Y
1 -0.88  0.05  1.33 -1.51  0.61 -0.09     2  8
2 -0.12 -0.57  0.05 -1.12  0.60 -0.41     1  7
3  0.14 -0.97 -1.04  0.40  0.87  0.27     1  9
4 -1.04 -0.26 -1.33  0.77 -1.84  1.67     1 11
5 -1.06  1.10 -0.09  0.50 -2.62  2.15     1 10
6 -1.74 -0.61  0.72 -0.29 -0.30 -0.93     1  8
```

Trying to run a model with all 6 terms does not work as the model is rank-deficient:

```
 #library(MuMIn) # not run
 #library(lme4) # not run
 vars<-names(dfdat)[1:6]
 form<-formula(paste0('Y~',paste0(vars,collapse='+'),'+(1|group)'))
 fmod<-glmer(form,data=dfdat,family='poisson')
 fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
 Error: pwrssUpdate did not converge in (maxit) iterations
```

Using `dredge` on `fmod` would lead to the one variable dropped by `glmer` being always excluded.

The solution, [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744959/dredge-with-the-global-model-failing-to-converge) seems to 1. run a model that converges, and 2.trick dredge into considering the full list of variables by changing the formula in the converged model.

```
## full model is rank deficient, so use smaller subset
vars.red<-vars[1:3]
form.red<-formula(paste0('Y~',paste0(vars.red,collapse='+'),'+(1|group)'))
fmod.red<-glmer(form.red,data=dfdat,family='poisson')
```

This new model `fmod.red` converges, but only includes variables X1,X2 and X3.

Now to the "tricking dredge" part. The solution proposed on the page linked above didn't work as such with `glmer` as the structure of `mermod` is different from gamms. So I tried to use:

```
fom.red@call$formula<-form
```

where `form` has all my covariates (to be subsetted).
This didn't work, but using the formula in the frame element, as suggested by Kamil Bartoń below, did work:

```
# replace formula in the frame element of fmod.red
attr(fmod.red@frame,"formula")<-form
# check
formula(fmod.red)
# now apply dredge function with covariates
# exclude variable combinations (randomly chosen for the sake of example)
sexpr<-expression(!((X1 && X3) || (X1&&X6) || (X4 && X6) || (X4 && X5)))
# run dredge()
options(na.action = na.fail)
ms<-dredge(fmod.red,subset=sexpr)
```

### UPDATE

While `ms` seemed to include all variables, as shown by:

```
names(ms)
[1] "(Intercept)" "X1"          "X2"          "X3"          "X4"          "X5"          "X6"         
[8] "df"          "logLik"      "AICc"        "delta"       "weight"
```

the new variables (X4,X5,X6) were never actually included (NAs everywhere):

```
summary(ms)
  (Intercept)          X1                X2                X3              X4        X5        X6    
 Min.   :2.407   Min.   :0.09698   Min.   :-0.4026   Min.   :-0.42078   +   : 0   +   : 0   +   : 0  
 1st Qu.:2.443   1st Qu.:0.22688   1st Qu.:-0.3204   1st Qu.:-0.35303   NA's:26   NA's:26   NA's:26  
 Median :2.474   Median :0.27361   Median :-0.2980   Median :-0.22444                                
 Mean   :2.535   Mean   :0.27539   Mean   :-0.3059   Mean   :-0.23517                                
 3rd Qu.:2.515   3rd Qu.:0.32357   3rd Qu.:-0.2718   3rd Qu.:-0.17472                                
 Max.   :3.009   Max.   :0.45664   Max.   :-0.2177   Max.   : 0.08802                                
             NA's   :20        NA's   :13        NA's   :16
```

What is happening?

Comment: any chance of a reproducible example ... ?

Comment: Hi Ben, I added some example code to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `"merMod"` objects, formula is first looked for at `attr(<object>@frame, "formula")` (see the function code of `getS3method("formula", "merMod")`). So, replacing it in a call element was not effective, which can be tested with `formula()` or `getAllTerms()`. Replace the `"formula"` attribute of `@frame`.

**Edit**: it turns out it isn't that easy to trick `dredge`, because it also looks at `coef` (or `fixef` in this case) when building the table. To work that around, first generate calls, `eval`uate, then build the table with `model.sel`:

```
model.sel(lapply(dredge(..., evaluate = FALSE), eval), ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I incorporated it in the question for future reference, I hope it's good practice.

Comment: Upon checking further, `dredge` did not seem to account for all variables, only the one in the reduced model, see Update.